# Un Mute Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to unmute command but I get an error and I don't know what the error is. Please help me
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

```
@client.command()
async def unmute(ctx, member):
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
    await ctx.send("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the argument type in the command:

```py
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```

And that will automatically look for a member based on what you've given in the argument. If no member is found, it will throw a `BadArgument` error which you can catch with either the `error` decorator or the `on_command_error` event.

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) - You'll need to `import discord` at the top of your code for this, if you haven't already.
- [`commands.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument)
- [`Command.error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error)
- [`Bot.on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error)